# Spark Write to S3 Storage Option

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am saving a spark dataframe to S3 bucket. The default storage type for the saved file is STANDARD. I need it to be STANDARD_IA. What is the option to achieve this. I have looked into the spark source codes and found no such options for spark DataFrameWriter in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala

Below is the code I am using to write to S3:

```
val df = spark.sql(<sql>)
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(<s3path>)
```

Edit: I am now using CopyObjectRequest to change the storage type of the created parquet:

```
val copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucket, key, bucket, key).withStorageClass(<storageClass>)
s3Client.copyObject(copyObjectRequest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of July 2022 this has been implemented in the hadoop source tree in [HADOOP-12020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12020) by AWS S3 engineers.

It is still stabilising and should be out in the next feature release of hadoop 3.3.x, due late 2022.

- anyone reading this before it ships: code is there to build yourself.
- anyone readying this in 2023+. upgrade to hadoop 3.3.5 or later

Comment: "Why not just define a lifecycle for the bucket and have things moved over every night?" - it's because you can move objects to OneZone AI only after 30 days. it makes a lot of sense to upload directly with OZ-IA

Comment: aah, that's a slightly different use case than glacier. if there's a way to mark files in that category during upload, it'd be viable. as usual: contributor to the oss codebase is expected to add new tests and declare which endpoint they ran the current tests against....

Comment: The difference between using a lifecycle policy and specifying storage class in the request is cost. former is priced at $0.01 per 1000 requests (objects) where the latter is free

Comment: updated the answer to 2022. you are free to check out hadoop branch-3.3 and do your own release through the same doc I am using today to create 3.3.4 RC1 (which doesn't support this) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/HowToRelease

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use the new feature from pyspark? I couldn't find any documentation for that.

Comment: i'd start by reading the hadoop s3a documentation